# Постоянное переполнение

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Пишу программу по расчёту мин. кол-ва банкнот и монет для набора суммы. При целых суммах всё нормально, но при вводе суммы с дробной части у 10-долларовой банкноты(почему-то только у неё, все остальные считаются правильно) происходят дикие вещи и переполнение. Не могу найти ошибку...помогите пожалуйста.

Код:
http://pastebin.com/sKgXSZDy

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale>
#include <windows.h>
//функция расчёта для количества купюр и монет при стандарт параметрах
void calculate(float summa, float bank[], float monet[],int kol_monet[],int kol_bank[])
{
    int i=0,p=0;
    while (summa!=0.0)
    {
        if (summa>=10.00)
        {
            if (summa>=bank[i])
            {
            summa=summa-bank[i];
            kol_bank[i]++;
            }
            else {i++;}
        }
        else 
        {
            if (summa>=monet[p])
            {
            summa=summa-monet[p];
            kol_monet[p]++;
            }
            else p++;
        }
    }
}  
//функция вывода при стандарт параметрах
void vivod(int kol_bank[],float bank[],float monet[],int kol_monet[])
{
        for(int k=0;k<=5;k++)
    {
        if(kol_bank[k]!=0)
        printf("%-.0f$: %i\n", bank[k], kol_bank[k]);
    }
    for(int k=0;k<=5;k++)
    {
        if(kol_monet[k]!=0)
        printf("%-3.2f: %i\n", monet[k], kol_monet[k]);
    }
}


void main()
{
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    float bank[]={5000,1000,500,100,50,10},monet[]={5,2,1,0.50,0.10,0.05},summa;
    int kol_bank[]={0,0,0,0,0,0},kol_monet[]={0,0,0,0,0,0};
    printf("Введите сумму: ");
    scanf("%f", &summa);
    calculate(summa, bank, monet,kol_monet,kol_bank);
    vivod(kol_bank,bank,monet,kol_monet);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы сравниваете переменную summa в условии цикла

```
while (summa != 0.0)
```

с нулем, забывая о погрешности представления десятичных чисел с помощью двоичных разрядов. Но это полбеды. Другие полбеды заключаются в том, что в вашем условии вы проверяете эту переменную на неравенство нулю, тогда как вам стоит ее проверять на то, больше ли она нуля. В итоге получается, что в один прекрасный момент после итераций по вот этому коду:

```
summa = summa - monet[p];
```

вы получаете в переменной summa не ровно 0.0 (как того стоило бы ожидать), а что-нибудь, чуть-чуть отличающееся от нуля, например 2.23517418e-8 (Это, еще раз напомню, происходит из-за погрешности представления десятичных дробей в памяти компьютера, оперирующего двоичными числами). И когда  в очередной раз проверяется условие

```
while (summa != 0.0)
```

то оно не прерывает цикл, так как это ваше 2.23517418e-8 != 0.0. А вследствие этого итерации цикла продолжаются, и вы выходите за пределы массива? и получаете не значение i-ого элемента, а некую кашу. Выход тут такой - сравнивать переменную summa не с нулем, а с неким Epsilon, который заведомо больше нуля, но меньше наименьшего из интересующих вас чисел. Например, 0.002 (больше нуля, но меньше 0.05).

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Поправил-заработало)